# window.opener.document.getElementById not working

Tags: asp.net, javascript

In my asp.net web app, I create a popup window with a button.  When that button is clicked, I want to set the value of an asp:TextBox (id=TextBox1) contained in the parent window.  However, it doesn't work like all the examples I've read indicate.

I've tried the following lines of code in my javascript onclick handler:

1. window.opener.document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = "abc";
2. window.opener.document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "abc";
3. window.opener.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1").value = "abc";

Only example 3 works.  All the stuff I've read indicates that #1 is the preferred method, but I can't seem to make it work at all.  Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried this in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Thanks

Comment: I'm no ASP programmer, but if your popup page is a *different* ASP page, then won't the `TextBox1` be unrelated to the `TextBox1` on the *parent* page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this line of JavaScript contained in the markup for the popup window itself? If so, the server-side code for that won't be aware that TextBox1 exists on the server-side code for the parent window, and won't be able to determine its ClientID property. You either need to pass that client ID to the popup window somehow (querystring, cookie, session, whatever) or hard code it. Alternatively, you may be able to put this line of JavaScript in a function on your parent page, and then call something along the lines of window.opener.functionName().

Answer (score 6):

you need to change a bit when calling your popup code , you have to pass your textbox client id and then you can set its value from popup page without any hard codding.
here is the way :

```
var txtNameClientObject = '<%= txtName.ClientID %>';
window.open('Child.aspx?txtName='+txtNameClientObject);
```

and then in popup page you  can do it as

```
opener.document.getElementById('<%= Request["txtName"] %>').value = 'from child';
```

hope this will be helpful for you.

Thanks